# Sending an email with Django is not working

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm new in Python & Django and I'm training myself with this wonderful language. I'm trying to send an email when an user is signing, the user is correctly created but no mail send.

I use one of my mail to test, here is the code:

models.py

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, company_name=None, company_id=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Vous devez entrer un email.')
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            company_name=company_name.upper(),
            company_id=company_id.upper()
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        send_mail('réussi', 'enfin', None, ['checkthegeek@protonmail.com'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("main:home")
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '***@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mhzvptzlqtylqzsn'

SERVER_EMAIL = '***@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '***@gmail.com'
```

What am I missing ? Thanks for your help.

send an email with django.